# Проблема с вводом-выводом бинарных файлов

Tags: c++, windows, файлы

Проблема возникает на этапе чтения из файла, так как я открыл файл hex редактором, и в нем число есть. Что я делаю не так?

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream fin("input.bin", ios::binary | ios::in);
    ofstream fout("input.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);

    int x = 499;
    int y;

    fout.write((char*)&x, sizeof(int));



    fin.read((char*)&y, sizeof(int));

    cout << y;


    fout.close();
    fin.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Смущает меня это **одновременное** открытие одного файла дважды... Вы проверяли - он точно открывается без ошибок?

Comment: @Harry А можно как-то иначе реализовать запись и считывание из одного файла?

Comment: @Harry Ну и да, я проверил, он открывается.

Comment: После записи данных нужно сделать `.flush()`. Кеш файловой системы и все дела...

Comment: @AlexGlebe Ничего не изменилось. А что вы имеет в виду под кешированием, что указатель не сбросится?

Comment: А проверил, у меня ok.

Comment: Кэш - это содержимое файла внутри памяти операционки. Иногда реальный файл меняется, тогда нужно принудительно очистить кеш и считать заново.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И все же считаю, что сначала нужно поработать с файлом на запись, закрыть, а уже потом работать на чтение.

Если у вас до начала программы файла нет - как вы его открываете для чтения?

```
int main()
{

    int x = 499;
    cout << "x= " << x << "\n";
    int y;

    ofstream fout("input.bin", ios::binary);

    if (!fout.is_open()) cout << "Error out\n";

    fout.write((char*)&x, sizeof(int));
    fout.close();

    ifstream fin("input.bin", ios::binary);

    if (!fin.is_open()) cout << "Error in\n";

    fin.read((char*)&y, sizeof(int));
    fin.close();

    cout << "y="<<y<<"\n";

}
```

Comment: Файл существует, он просто открывает его в другом "pipe'е", если в Windows есть такое понятие. Ну и да, я проверил ваш код, он так же не работает.

Comment: Плохо проверили. Если права на создание/чтение есть - все работает. Вы случайно не в каком-нибудь онлайн-компиляторе тестируете? Где права работать с файлами отобраны? :)

Comment: Дописал пару строк - проверьте, открываются ли у вас файлы (я это писал еще в самом первом комментарии).

Comment: Нет, MSVC. Ну и да, я проверил hex-редактором с записью все в порядке, проблема с чтением.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de13236632264fd8

Comment: Проверил, он не может открыть fout.

Answer (score 0):

После записи данных нужно сделать `.flush()`. Кэш файловой системы и все дела...

```
// g++ -Wall -std=c++11 input.cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream fin("input.bin", ios::binary | ios::in);
    ofstream fout("input.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);

    int x = 499;
    cout << "x="<<x<<"\n";
    int y;

    fout.write((char*)&x, sizeof(int));

      fout.flush();


    fin.read((char*)&y, sizeof(int));

    cout << "y="<<y<<"\n";


    fout.close();
    fin.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Я полностью скопировал код, и он не работает, т.е. с переменной x все хорошо, но в у - мусор.

Comment: Может у нас другая операционка, тогда последний шанс : добавьте `fin.sync()` перед чтением.

Comment: К сожалению, не работает.

Comment: Тогда ничем не помочь. В файловых системах иногда при открытии файла на запись, меняется расположение - другие сектора диска. И ваш открытый поток уже имеет другое имя в корзине.

Comment: Да, но если бы была эта проблема, то ее можно было решить путем закрытия потока после записи, и открытия перед чтением, но так это не решается.